# javafx navigate to the previous form through button

Tags: button, javafx, back

I have an intro form which include buttons. After click on them, it directs me to other forms that i have already customize. How can i go to the previous form?
Is there any sample for back button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use the same logic for the back button as you are using for next form in `next` button !

Comment: I mean on every view, you have a `next button` that take you to the `next view`. In the same view, your `back button` can be bounded to the `previous view` that you want to go !